# Errno::ECONNREFUSED No connection could be made because

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, compass-sass, compass

I'm having trouble installing ruby gems. When I run

```
gem install compass
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'compass' (>= 0), here is why: 
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ 
- no such name (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Having tried to find the answer to this particular problem I can to the conclusion (with the help of google) that the fact I'm behind a corporate proxy is blocking the connection to Rubygems.org

So with a bit more googling I found this command that people have used to succesfully connect when behind a proxy

```
gem install compass --http-proxy=http://%USERNAME%:%PASSWORD%@%PROXY_SERVER%:%PROXY_PORT_NUMBER%
```

Having run this command substituting in the relevant information I'm not getting a different error.

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'compass' (>= 0), here is why:
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ECONNREFUSED: 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
- connect(2) (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

I've had no luck finding what could be cuasing it, can anyone help?

Alternatively does anyone know of a way to install SASS and or Compass without using a Ruby CLI?

FYI I've tried a few SASS Preprocessor apps (PREPOS) and the compass app but we need specific versions of both SASS and COMPASS for this project and i can't seem to downgrade them.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to use environment variables to set the proxies:

```
export http_proxy="http://user:pass@server.com:port"
export HTTP_PROXY="http://user:pass@server.com:port"
```

and then try to install the gem normally.

To test the proxy environment you can use cURL or wget:

```
curl -I http://stackoverflow.com
wget http://stackoverflow.com
```

Read [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/571887/172771) if you want to know about the upper and lower case variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables. For example:

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://%USERNAME%:%PASSWORD%@%PROXY_SERVER%:%PROXY_PORT_NUMBER% gem install compass
```