# Error on installing compass on terminal: Connection refused - Connection refused

Tags: terminal, rubygems, sudo, http-proxy, compass

I was trying to install compass on my OS X terminal using the following command:

```
sudo gem install compass
```

but an error prompt:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'compass' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - Connection refused (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz) ERROR:  Possible alternatives: compass
```

What's causing this?

I then googled and found the same issue here:

[Errno::ECONNREFUSED No connection could be made because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626910/errnoeconnrefused-no-connection-could-be-made-because)

But I don't understand how the following command can resolve the issue:

```
Try to use environment variables to set the proxies:
export http_proxy="http://user:pass@server.com:port"
export HTTP_PROXY="http://user:pass@server.com:port"
```

I am only installing compass on my localhost. What should the USER, PASS, and @SERVER be replaced with? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully installed compass now after fixing my proxy via this link:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-proxy-environment-variable/

Basically I just did the following commands on the terminal:

```
$ export http_proxy=http://server-ip:port/
$ export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128/
```