# set http_proxy not working on windows

Tags: windows, proxy

I am using Windows 7. I was trying to install jekyll using : gem install jekyll

I get an error: Unable to download data from .... connection timed out.

So I tried to set http_proxy and https_proxy by :

```
set http_proxy = http://proxy:port
set https_proxy = https://proxy:port
```

I still get the same error. I think that somehow the above commands are not working. 
So my question is how do I check if http_proxy is set to what I have set it to? and if the above command has worked then how can if fix the problem.
My internet connection is fine when I use it on browser.

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059670/how-to-set-proxy-for-command-prompt) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626910/errnoeconnrefused-no-connection-could-be-made-because) link.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First remove spaces beetween `=` .
Then type set without parameter to check your environment variables